# AlertDialog dialog.dismiss(), dialog.close() not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I have to click twice in the button (any: positive, neutral, and negative) for it to dismiss the AlertDialog.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.View
import com.example.said.puntodeventa.R.layout.layout_addproduct

class someClass : AppCompatActivity() {

@SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid")
private fun someDialog(){
AlertDialog.Builder(this).apply {
                setTitle("title")
                setMessage("message")
                setNegativeButton("No"){ dialog, which ->
                    anEditText.text.clear()
                    anEditText.requestFocus()
                    dialog.cancel()
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                setNeutralButton("Neutral"){ dialog, which ->
                    someEditText.text.clear()
                    someEditText.requestFocus()
                    dialog.cancel()
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, which ->
                    addProduct()
                    dialog.cancel()
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                create()
                show()
            }
        }

private fun addProduct(){
        //some code working properly
    }
}
```

`addProduct()` and `.text.clear()` work perfectly, but the AlertDialog does not close the first time I click on it.

I've tried using only with `dialog.cancel()`, `dialog.dismiss()` separately and nothing seems to work, like the code is not there.

I've also tried import `android.app.AlertDialog` with the same results.

This is the red text in the log when I click any of the buttons, it does not matter if it is the first time (when the AlertDialog does not close) or the second (when it actually closes).

```
05-19 16:42:34.543 24647-24647/com.example.name.appdemo E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familar with Kotlin, but shouldn't there be a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` in the button definition? Something like `dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, whichButton ->
            //pass
        })`?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel() Check this doc as you are using dialog.cancel() which is cancelling your dialog and thus you cannot dismiss it

Comment: Chek my answer please, It doesn't need DialogInterface.OnClickListener and also I only used dialog.dismiss() and still need two clicks to close. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@Said : 
i copy your code and it works perfectly, only need 1 click to close the positive or negative button, so i believe the problems is not in this part.

```
private fun dialogCostPrice(){

    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Dialog Title")
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Dialog Message")
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", { dialog, whichButton ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    })
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", { dialog, whichButton ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    })
    val b = dialogBuilder.create()
    b.show()
    }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, check my comment to @"Dav id", I found out there's something weird when I call the principal function when using the `someEditText.onKeyListener`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't for get to define the listener for the on click event `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`:

```
fun showDialog() {
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val inflater = this.layoutInflater
    val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null)
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)

    val editText = dialogView.findViewById<View>(R.id.editTextName) as EditText

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Dialog Title")
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Dialog Message")
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, whichButton ->
        //get what you need here!
    })
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, whichButton ->
        //get what you need here!
    })
    val b = dialogBuilder.create()
    b.show()
}
```

Comment: Call me crazy, I copied an pasted your answer and still need two clicks to close it. The Android Studio 3.0 says I don't need the DialogInterface.OnClickLIstener because is a "Redundant SAM-constructor". BTW you set two setPositiveButton so I changed one. I will post my code as answer to this topic so you can see it with format

Comment: @Said :: Unfortunately, I am not that familiar with Kotlin. I wish I could have been able to help you more!

Answer (score 1):

`AlertDialog` dismisses automatically when you click on any button, so there is no need to write dismiss() or cancel().

I suppose you are showing the dialog twice and that's why you think that it needs 2 clicks to dismiss.

Here is the code which works just fine:

```
 private fun dialogCostPrice() {
    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Dialog Title")
            .setMessage("Dialog Message")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", { dialog, whichButton ->

            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", { dialog, whichButton ->

            }).show()
}
```

And YES `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` is redundant in kotlin.

Comment: Yes you are right, I realized I'm having this problem when calling the main function from `someEditText.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener({ v, keyCode, k ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                principal()
                return@OnKeyListener true
            }
            false
        }))` so I'm gonna have to change that, ENTER will only check the EditText required format and the addButton.setOnClickListener will be the only allowed to save. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also write

```
alertDialog.setOnDismissListener { dialog ->
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
```